# Dundas / Microsoft charting stacked area chart multiple series with mixture of positive and negatives

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, dundas

I would like to create a stacked area chart which contains multiple series, however we would like all the positive values to be stacked positively (above the X axis) and all the negative values to be stacked negatively (below the X axis).

The stacked area series doesn't appear to be creating the desired effect.  Its a little difficult to explain but if there are 4 series and series 1, 2 had a positive data point these would stack upward away from the x axis.  If series 3 had a negative data point the series would be rendered from the cumulative peak of 1 and 2 down toward the x axis, finally the 4 series would be render from the cumulative of the 1, 2, and 3 series.

I'm using (legacy) Dundas charts, the version just before Microsoft bought the IP and created the Microsoft Charting Visualisation in .NET.  A switch to us this instead could be on the cards so if the ideas involve this too that would be great.

Can anyone please suggest some ideas or ways to achieve this using either technologies.

Are we using the wrong type of chart perhaps?

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 0):

Dundas Data Visualisation has a demo of what they call a "Waterfall Chart" here: http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard3.Samples_Chart_WaterfallChart.ashx

As far as I know, you would need to "upgrade" to after Microsoft bought the IP.  Perhaps you can look at the demo scripts and hack a workaround with what you have?  I didn't get on the Dundas train until Microsoft bought them, so I don't know.

I hope this helps.